# RadDatePicker selectable Dates

Tags: wpf, telerik, raddatepicker

I'm working with Teleriks RadDatePicker and need to disable a various count of dates for the user.

I started with the `SelectableDateStart` and `SelectableDateEnd` Properties.

```
<telerik:RadDatePicker VerticalAlignment="Center"
        SelectableDateEnd="{Binding Path=SelectableDateEnd}"
        SelectableDateStart="{Binding Path=SelectableDateStart}"
        SelectedValue="{Binding Path=SelectedTimeWindow}" />
```

Is there a way to bind a list with selectable Dates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to bind a list with selectable Dates, but you can set `BlackoutDates` which contains a list of dates that cannot be selected.

You should follow these step:

1. Set `SelectableDateStart` - the first date that can be selected ([SelectableDateStart doc](http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/wpf/api/html/P_Telerik_Windows_Controls_RadDateTimePicker_SelectableDateStart.htm))
2. Set `SelectableDateEnd` - the last date that can be selected ([SelectableDateEnd doc](http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/wpf/api/html/P_Telerik_Windows_Controls_RadDateTimePicker_SelectableDateEnd.htm))
3. Set `BlackoutDates` - a list of dates that cannot be selected ([BlackoutDates doc](http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/wpf/api/html/P_Telerik_Windows_Controls_RadDateTimePicker_BlackoutDates.htm))